# Command Prompt returning error "Python was not found" when running python commands despite being properly installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I am facing an issue where I can run Python seamlessly within Visual Studio Code and the Python terminal. However, when I try to create a Python virtual environment using the command python -m venv venv or check the Python version with python --version, I encounter the following error message:

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

I have attempted to resolve this by uninstalling and reinstalling Python multiple times, and I even downloaded it from the Microsoft Store as prompted. Despite Python being successfully installed and capable of executing Python commands, the Command Prompt does not recognize its presence on my computer.

I even created a new folder containing a blank Python file and attempted to create a virtual environment from there, but the issue persists. My research into this problem has not yielded any conclusive explanations. Can anyone provide insights into why this might be happening?

Comment: Visual Studio Code can use `/full/path/to/python`. If you run code outside IDE you may also need to use `/full/path/to/python`, or you have to add `/full/path/to` (without `python`) to variable `PATH` and system will know where to search `python` when you run it without full path.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Comment: @JialeDu I solved the issue, although I'm unsure about the exact reason. Initially, I deleted all versions of Python and attempted to reinstall it using Microsoft's installer, but that didn't work. I went back to it a few days later, and it was fixed. I'm assuming it had something to do with just restarting my computer after getting rid of the non-working python versions.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add Python to your `PATH` environment variable. See https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/ .

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the full python path as the command.
For example `E:\Desktop\project\.venv\Scripts\python.exe --version`.

Of course, you can also add the environment variable path. You can also check this setting when installing python.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.**

I am using Windows 11. I 've got this error, but i tried to resolve this issue by reinstalling python by python website. But vs code getting same error. Finally I resolved that by typing Microsoft store in windows search. Then type the python in Microsoft store search and select the python version and get it. After downloading then it was resolved.